# Template recursive structure with apache velocity

Tags: java, velocity

I have a recursive data structure, basically a tree, where a node may have child nodes and so on. I'm trying to generate a JSON-like file of that structure. For that thought of using the `#parse` directive. In the context i store the root node and in templateName the template's name.

```
{
    "name" = "$node.name",
    "value" = "$node.value"

    #if ($node.childrens.size() > 0)
    ,
    "childrens" = {
        #foreach ($child in $node.childrens)
            ## The next statement does not work
            #parse ($child.type + ".vm", $child)
        #end
    }
    #end
}
```

The apache velocity documentation states that the `#parse` directive [only takes one argument](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#parse).

In examples I have seen the use of the `#set` directive before calling another template, but if the depth of the tree is higher than 2 this does not work because the variable used in the `#set` directive is stored in the same context so when going from depth 1 to 2 the variable would be overwritten.

The reason to use `#parse` instead of a macro as suggested by @Sergiu Dumitriu is because each node may be rendered in a different way depending on it's property `$node.type`. I would like to have a template for each type so one person adding a template for a particular type does not have to mess with any other template, I mean, maybe this could be achieved having a switch on the type property; but that implies that all ways of rendering will be defined in the same file.

Is there any way of using Velocity to apply templates to recursive data structures?

---

**Solution**
Based on both answers from Sergiu Dumitriu the final template looks like:

```
#macro ( displayNode $node)
{
    #set ( $parseNode = $node )
    #set ( $parseTemplate = $parseNode.type + ".vm" )
    #parse ( $parseTemplate )
    #set ( $parseNode = $node )
    #set ( $parseTemplate = "Common.vm" )
    #parse ( $parseTemplate )
}
#end
```

The `Common.vm` has the structure shown in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not use `#parse`, since it's a somewhat costly operation. [Define a macro and use it recursively](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html#Velocimacros) instead.

```
#macro(displayNode $node)
{
    "name" = "$node.name",
    "value" = "$node.value"##
    #if ($node.childrens.size() > 0),
    "childrens" = {
        #foreach ($child in $node.children)
            #displayNode($child)
        #end
    }
    #end
}
#end
```

If the template name is also variable, you can use [`#evaluate`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/vtl-reference-guide.html#aevaluate_-_Dynamically_evaluates_a_string_or_reference) to construct the template name dynamically:

```
        #set ($d = '$')
        #foreach ($child in $node.children)
            #evaluate("#display${child.type}Node(${d}child)")
        #end
```

Comment: I didn't think if that, it might get the job done. The reason I did go with parse is because each node may be displayed in a different way depending on a type property of the node. That is why I used `#parse`. This wasn't clear stated in the question so I have updated to reflect that fact.

Comment: A recursive macro works, the macro arguments seem to be local to that macro call. I also used the `#set` before the `#parse` provided in your other answer, so in the end the solution was a mix of both.

Answer (score 3):

To overcome the fact that by default in Velocity variables are global, you could use local variables in the current scope. Velocity has [several options](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/developer-guide.html#Velocity_Configuration_Keys_and_Values) for enabling different local scopes, including a template scope created whenever rendering a template, `template.provide.scope.control`. The problem is that this is disabled by default, so you have to configure Velocity to have it activated. After you activate this, you'll automatically have a `$template` variable which you can use to store local variables.

```
## The first thing to do is to copy the $node value into a local scope
## that won't be overwritten by nested calls
#set ($template.node = $node)
{
    "name" = "$template.node.name",
    "value" = "$template.node.value"##
    #if ($template.node.childrens.size() > 0),
    "childrens" = {
        #foreach ($child in $template.node.children)
            ## $template.node doesn't change, so now $node can be freely reassigned
            #set ($node = $child)
            #parse("${child.type}.vm")
        #end
    }
    #end
}
```